# REST endpoint, get nested resource with unique ID

Tags: rest, url, api-design

I have the following dilemma while designing some endpoints. We have items that always belong to orders so it felt natural to got with the following endpoint for creation of an item:

```
POST /orders/{orderid}/items
```

However this item has a unique ID, meaning we can fetch it without knowing the parent order. This means that the following is unnecessarily elaborate:

```
GET  /orders/{orderid}/items/{itemid}
```

At the same time it feels inconsistent to use it without the orderid because it was created with, like:

```
GET /orders/items/{itemid}
```

And also, one would get all items belonging to an order using the following for example:

GET /orders/{orderid}/items

One could even go as far as to say that, because we don't need to know the parent we can simplify it to:

```
GET /items/{itemid}
```

I've read quite a few post on the subject so far, but have not found any suggestions for this specific case.

So what is the way to go here? Is there even a specific way to go, a best practice?